# apt-get error while loading shared libraries libzstd.so.1 cannot open shared object file no such file or directory

Tags: debian, apt

I was trying to upgrade a system but I was getting a,

You don't have enough free space in /var/cache/apt/archives/.

I tried to `apt-get autoremove`, `apt-get clean` and still nothing.

There is no space left at root:

http://prntscr.com/o20ccl

And then read [somewhere](https://forum.siduction.org/index.php?topic=5944.15) that, installing [libapt-pkg5.0](https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/bionic/main/updates/libapt-pkg5.0) manually that this issue could be fixed, so I tried to install but there was some missing dependencies and it stops, then I notice that I was no longer able to use `apt` anymore.

I have also reboot this system, but the problem persists. I have also run `sudo ldconfig`, but same result.

Do you know how can I solve this?

If you need more info do help feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like I have installed a non compatible libapt-pkg5.0 for my debian 9 so I just downloaded the right version of that lib,

```
wget http://ftp.br.debian.org/debian/pool/main/a/apt/libapt-pkg5.0_1.4.9_amd64.deb
```

and install it through,

```
dpkg -i libapt-pkg5.0_1.4.9_amd64.deb
```

and it came back to live again.